# Queries on munkres lemma 41.3

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres Topology chapter 6 lemma 41.3(page 254)

Lemma 41.3:

Let $X$ be regular. Then the following conditions on $X$ are equivalent:

Every open covering of $X$ has a refinement that is:

1. An open covering of $X$ and countably locally finite
2. A covering of $X$ and locally finite
3. A closed covering of $X$ and locally finite
4. An open covering of $X$ and locally finite

In the proof of (2)$\Rightarrow$(3) (and (3)$\Rightarrow$(4)), Munkres constructs a covering $\mathscr{C}$ and seems to assume that it is countably locally finite as it uses (2) (and (3))

> (2)$\Rightarrow$(3):
>
> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an open covering of $X$. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the collection of all open sets $U$ of $X$ such that $\overline{U}$ is contained in an element of $A$. By regularity, $B$ covers $X$. Using (2), we can find a refinement $\mathscr{C}$ of $\mathscr{B}$ that covers $X$ and is locally finite.

In order to use (2) it seems like $\mathscr{B}$ is assumed to be countably locally finite. But suppose we let $\mathscr{B}$ be the collections of open sets in the lower limit topology that is contained in $[0,1)$, it doesn't seem like this collection is countably locally finite.

Similarly,

> (3)$\Rightarrow$(4):
>
> For each point $x$ of $X$, there is a neighborhood of $x$ that intersects only finitely many elements of $\mathscr{B}$. The collection of all open sets that intersect only finitely many elements of $\mathscr{B}$ is thus an open covering of $X$. Using (3) again, let $\mathscr{C}$ be a closed refinement of this covering that covers $X$ and is locally finite.

Which also assumes $\mathscr{B}$ is countably locally finite

My doubt is how is $\mathscr{B}$ is countably locally finite in both cases, since it doesn't seem to be in the specific case mentioned above.

Edit 1: The structure of the proof is pretty clear, it's just that using (2) or (3) assumes (1), which states that the covering have a refinement that is countably locally finite, not all coverings in regular spaces are countably locally finite, for instance $R_\ell^2$ is regular but not paracompact

Edit 2: So the assumption at first was that every open covering, not just a single open covering, so $\mathscr{B}$ by assumption is countably locally finite

Comment: Using (2) does not assume (1) at all. The 4 statements are all of the form “for every open cover of $X$ there is a refinement cover” which has possibly some extra condition. Munkres, as a shorthand, only mentions the extra condition without repeating the common part.

Comment: No $\mathcal{B}$ is *not* by assumption countably locally finite; you still misunderstand the structure of the statements and thus the structure of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the proof is a classical "round trip" of implications: so we assume $(2)$ holds ("every open cover has a locally finite refinement"; where this refinement is just any cover of $X$, the elements can be any type of set) and show $(3)$: "every open cover has a locally finite closed refinement".

So to show $(3)$, we start with an open cover $\mathcal{A}$ (and we can assume $(2)$ as a fact), but first we define an other related cover (**not** locally finite, in general ) $$\mathcal{B}=\{U: \text{ open }: \exists A \in \mathcal{A}: \overline{U}\subseteq A\}$$

This is a cover indeed: let $x\in  X$, as $\mathcal{A}$ is an open cover there is some $A_x \in \mathcal{A} $ with $x \in A_x$. By regularity there is an open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $x \in U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq A_x$. Then $U \in \mathcal{B}$ as witnessed by $A_x$ and $x \in U$.

Now apply $(2)$ to this cover $\mathcal{B}$, and we get a *locally finite* $\mathcal{C}$ that is a cover of $X$ and refines $\mathcal{B}$. Then he probably goes on to show that

$$\mathcal{C}'=\{\overline{C}: C \in \mathcal{C}\}$$

is a *closed* locally finite cover of $X$, where we can maybe rely on some old fact that when a family of set is locally finite, so is the set of its closures.
That it is indeed a cover and refines the original $\mathcal{A}$ is easy to check from definitions.

$(3)$ to $(4)$ is similar: we start with an open cover, define a related open cover, and apply $(3)$ to that related cover, and "manipulate" the (locally finite) result to show $(4)$, and get a refinement of the right type for the original open cover.

Comment: Also see my note [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/03.pdf) for the same proof.

Comment: the cover $\mathscr{B}$ may not be countably locally finite tho, and to use (2) you need it to be countably locally finite

Comment: @Ariana you misunderstand what $(2)$ says. It says: "every open cover of $X$ has  a locally finite refinement". We apply it to the open cover $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: oh right yea i think i misunderstood it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For any conditional statement, $P \Rightarrow Q$, the statement evaluates to true for all possible truth values of $P,Q$ except $T \Rightarrow F = F$, but $F \Rightarrow Q = T, T\Rightarrow T = T$. So, the assumption is warranted to prove the conditional statement. You need only consider the case when $P$ is true and prove the implication is that $Q$ is also true.

In your example, if you want to prove that (2) implies (3), then assume (2) is true, and use its truth to prove that (3) is also true.

Comment: yea but it is now constructing a new covering and it uses (2) to get a locally finite covering, but that assumes it is countably locally finite in the first place(since (1)$\Rightarrow$(2))

Comment: The new covering is not assumed to be countably locally finite. It is declared to be locally finite, with countable local finiteness not required. The idea is $X \Rightarrow (1) \Rightarrow (2) \Rightarrow (3) \Rightarrow (4) \Rightarrow (1)$ shows equivalence. So, if you want to get back to see how it is countably locally finite, get all the way to 4 and follow the book's proof to return to (1).

Comment: yea but like you can just declare a arbitrary covering as locally finite

Comment: You are assuming that an arbitrary covering can be refined to a locally finite covering by the assumption of (2).

Comment: Yea realized that the assumption was all open coverings not just for a single open covering